# Can i use raspberry pi 5 into low power mode programmatically?

Tags: pi-5, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am using raspberry pi 5. In which my service is running and it is doing some task for sometime.After completion of task i want raspberry pi to go in sleep mode and consume low power.Can i do it with programmatically or any other way is there?

Comment: The Pi does not have a sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **sleep mode** available on the RPi5 (or any other RPi) as there is no hardware to support it.

The best you can do with the RPi5 is to press the "soft power" button. This will execute a safe shutdown, and put the RPi5 into a lower (not zero!) power consumption state. Another press will bring the RPi5 back to "life".

There are also some EEPROM settings you can make that will reduce the RPi5 power consumption to near zero - but only when it is in the shutdown mode.

There are methods by which you can ***programmatically control*** the RPi5 to turn it ON or OFF, but these require additional hardware ([ex 1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136085/83790); [ex 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130443/83790)). If you're interested in something like that, I'd suggest you post another question as this one isn't *specific* enough to warrant expending any time on it.